# How to solve this weird caching issue in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, caching

I'm running into a weird caching issue, which I don't understand how to fix it.

I load a json file:

```
$json       = file_get_contents($filename);
```

This is the content of the json file:

```
[{"Original":"original_1","Replacement":"replacement_1"},{"Original":"original_2","Replacement":"replacement_2"}
```

The content is fresh. When I edit the json file content and reload it, a dump shows that $json contains the actual content.

The json file contains words and their replacements. I will use these in a string replace routine:

```
$srarr      = json_decode($json, true);
$original   = array_column($srarr, 'Original');
$replacement= array_column($srarr, 'Replacement');
$text_after = str_ireplace($original, $replacement, $text);
```

The values in $original show the actual (fresh) original words. (a dump shows they're up to date and not cached)

The values in $replacement also show the actual (fresh) replacement words. (also up to date and not cached)

But the variable $text_after contains old cached replacement versions of replacement words that are not in $replacement.

These replacement words are not in the json file anymore, not in $srarr and not in $replacement.

Still the final result is that $text_after contains these old replacement words.

Somehow it looks like the old values are cached somewhere. But where? And how do I flush this cache everytime? Or how do I prevent this caching?

I tried adding `opcache_invalidate(__FILE__, true);` but that doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Perhaps [Tell me more about cache](https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/): Pressing ctrl + F5 (windows) or Apple + R (mac) could help.

Comment: The opcache caches the code, not data. AFAIK, PHP never caches data. The only cache would be on the client if you're calling the script with a `GET` request. But then you would see the old versions of all the variables, not just `$text_after`.

Answer (score 0):

After all it was not a caching issue. The issue was that parts of larger words were also replaced instead of whole words only. That changed the final text and other replacements could not be found anymore.

It looked like I was dealing with a caching issue, but in fact it was my misinterpretation of the functionality of the str_ireplace function.

I changed the code into preg_replace and put it in a 'for' loop. With preg_replace it's possible to replace whole words only.

If anyone has a similar issue, maybe the following code can help:

```
    if (file_exists($filename)) {

        $json       = file_get_contents($filename);
        $json       = '['.$json.']';
        
        $srarr      = json_decode($json, true);
        $ori_arr    = array_column($srarr, 'Original');
        $rep_arr    = array_column($srarr, 'Replacement');

        $count = count($ori_arr);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $text    = preg_replace("/\b$ori_arr[$i]\b/",$rep_arr[$i],$text);
        }           
    }
```